# Dynamodb Single Table vs Partition Size

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

There are two guidelines for Dynamodb design

1. Use a single Table
2. Make sure Partition size are approximately the same size for good performance
   These two can easily conflict e.g storing Address and Orders in the same table for a customer
   Your orders for a customer will vastly outnumber the Addresses.
   How to handle such a situation with the same table?
   I am anticipating very different partition sizes for my data should I create multiple tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how DynamoDB partitions data on your behalf. It is not that DynamoDB partitions need to be the same size, it is that the items should be as evenly distributed amongst the partitions as possible. There are multiple mechanisms that help with this, but it all starts with a good data model. Since you do not post a data model for consideration, it is difficult to know how to help you further.